# ArrayList and Polymorphism

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

It would be of great help, if someone can point out the problem and possible explanation here.

```
class Parent{}    
public class ChildClass extends Parent{ 
  /*Main class*/    
  public static void main(String[] args) {  

      ArrayList<ChildClass> a3 = new ArrayList<ChildClass>();   
      foo(a3);      
    }
  /*another function*/
  static void foo(ArrayList<Parent> obj) {      
}
```

This throws the following compilation error.

```
The method foo(ArrayList<Parent>) in the type ChildClass is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<ChildClass>)
```

The rule of Polymorphism should allow me to do it. Right? After all the ChildClass IS-A Parent. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Type `static void foo(ArrayList<? extends Parent> obj) {}` instead.

Comment: Thanks you but I wanted an explanation of why it was not compiling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ChildClass` is-a `Parent`, but `ArrayList<ChildClass>` is-not-an `ArrayList<Parent>`. If you consider this code, it shoud be clear why:

```
ArrayList<ChildClass> a3 = new ArrayList<>();
foo(a3);
ChildClass c = a3.get(0);

...

static void foo(ArrayList<Parent> obj) {
   obj.add(new Parent());
}
```

If the above code happened to compile without error, it would be type-unsafe and actually fail at runtime with `ClassCastException`.

So, for the relation "`ArrayList<ChildClass>` is-a `ArrayList<Parent>`" to actually make sense, these two facts would have to be simultaneously true:

1. `ChildClass` is-a `Parent`;
2. `Parent` is-a `ChildClass`.

In general, that can be true only if `ChildClass` is the same type as `Parent`, under a different name. So we arrive at the real rule Java applies, which is called *type invariance*: it neither holds that `ArrayList<ChildClass>` is-an `ArrayList<Parent>`, nor that `ArrayList<Parent>` is-an `ArrayList<ChildClass>`.

Comment: So the overall point is that ArrayList<parent> will only take parent and nothing else and same is true for ArrayList<child>. That's because when we pop up the values, it doesn't know which object is being extracted. Right? P.S. The above code also does not compile for me in my eclipse. Anyways I got the point.

Comment: You can add child to `ArrayList<Parent>`, but you can't pass an `ArrayList<Child>` to a method which expects `ArrayList<Parent>`. As for compilation, these are two snippets of code and don't compile as-is. You must include the first part into a method (such as `main`).